# Can't get Excel Scatter Chart to correlate labels with X/Y coords

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel sheet, shown here:
[image]

I want the highlighted X/Y coordinates to be labeled by the highlighted text on the same row.

On a different sheet in the same workbook, I have an Excel Scatter Chart:
[image]

With this data:

[image]

Despite feeding it the data in my chosen columns (E for label and J/K as X/Y points), the labels on the X/Y points don't match the label on the same row the X/Y points are gotten from.

The labels on the chart is from the correct column, but not correlated with the same row the X/Y data was gotten from.

Clearly I'm misunderstanding something. How can I make the labels in column E apply to the J/K data *from the same row*?

**[Edit:]** More confusingly, it seems to correlate, but eight rows lower down the column from the X/Y coordinates paired with it. But I've triple-checked my starting row I'm feeding to the chart...

Basically, the chart shows the values from these rows:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not doable without using VBA or add-ons.

[This article](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s130/excel-chart-data-labels-vba-loops.htm) explains a simple bit of VBA code to label the points.

I've modified it to fit the situation above. It has to be triggered manually by clicking a button, however.

```
Sub ApplyChartLabelsFromRange(chartName As String, labelColumn As String, startingRow As Integer)
    
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Set myChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName)
    
    Dim chartSeries As Series
    Set chartSeries = myChart.chart.SeriesCollection(1)
    chartSeries.HasDataLabels = True

    Dim row As Integer
    row = startingRow 'Our starting row

    Dim chartPoint As Point
    For Each chartPoint In chartSeries.Points
        'Apparently the Excel chart creates every Point even if they have empty cells in the range,
        'so I don't need to worry about skipping empty cells.
        
        'If IsNumeric(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(row, "J").Value) Then
            chartPoint.DataLabel.Text = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(row, labelColumn).Value
        'End If
        
        row = row + 1
    Next chartPoint
End Sub

Sub HideChartLabels(chartName As String)
    
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Set myChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName)
    
    Dim chartSeries As Series
    Set chartSeries = myChart.chart.SeriesCollection(1)
    'If we merely set this to false, it'd hide the labels, but also lose all label formatting for when we re-show the labels.
    'So, instead, we just change the label text.
    chartSeries.HasDataLabels = True
    
    Dim myPoint As Point
    For Each myPoint In chartSeries.Points
        myPoint.DataLabel.Text = ""
    Next myPoint
End Sub

Sub Map_ShowLabels()
    Call ApplyChartLabelsFromRange("Tree Map", "E", 7)
End Sub

Sub Map_HideLabels()
    Call HideChartLabels("Tree Map")
End Sub
```